# Python import with as

Tags: python-3.x, import, modular

I have to files in the same folder

First: (module1.py)

```
a = 2*np.pi
```

Second: (MainProg.py)

```
import numpy as np
from module1 import a 

print(np.pi)
print(a)
```

When running MainProg.py the error tells me that name np in np.pi is not defined in module1.py. Do I have to extra import numpy as np in modul1.py?

Comment: Why import numpy in the second file if it's used in the first?

Comment: yes, you do, you should import the module where you use it, but you don't need to import it in MainProg.py

Comment: You should import numpy in the file where you're trying to use it.

Comment: I want to define some statements in an extra file while using the main programm. I need numpy in both files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to.

Why ? because when you import a file in python, this file will be executed. So when your "module1.py" will be executed it will return you an error because "np" is inexistent.

EDIT: Don't see the import in python as a code replacement of the file you imported in your current file.
The import will import functions that are in the file you are importing, and execute all codes that is not inside a python function or in the __main__.

Comment: Okay I understand. So when planing the usage of numpy in both files I have to import it to both?

Comment: Yes you have to !